# Reset @Input property in Angular component

Tags: angular

Can anyone help me with this problem.
I need @Input() message to reset each time component is updated with a new person.

In component.ts

```
export class MessageComponent {
   @Input() message: string;
   person: Person;

   ngOnInit() {
      this.service.getPerson()
         .subscribe((data: Person) => this.person = data);
   }
```

In component.html

```
<div>{{ message }}</div>
```

Comment: **this.message = null** maybe ?

Comment: Does the parent need to update its value when message updated?

Comment: @MajiD yes, but where will I put this?

Comment: @kswang what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Put it in the subscription of your getPerson method because that's where you're updating the person.

Comment: What value should message reset to?

Answer (score 0):

this.message =  in a component from which you are calling MessageComponent as a Child

Comment: Yes that's possible, but I would like to handle it in MessageComponent instead. If possible.

Comment: do it in ngOnChanges lifecycle hook

Comment: No, it only triggers when message is changes. I want it to reset every time,

Comment: What do you mean by every time?